# One third of Lyapunov exponents are zero? What does it mean?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, stability, chaos-theory, complex-systems

This may be quite a straightforward question, but I have a dynamical system with a high dimensional phase-space. I calculated the Lyapunov spectrum for it and saw that one third of my Lyapunov exponents are approximately zero (which is a lot and was quite unexpected).

What can I conclude from this? These do not signify stable manifolds in the phase-space as you would need negative Lypaunov exponents for this I guess. Does this signify like a giant oscillatory motion in my phase-space? What can I deduce from this abundance of zero modes in the spectrum?

Sidenote: This is a Hamiltonian system so that all Lyapunov exponents sum to zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What first comes to my mind is that you're probably sampling invariant **quasiperiodic tori**, which are typically neutrally stable.

The associated motion is regular, but not periodic, in that the phase space trajectory comes arbitrarily close to previous states, but never exactly repeats itself (hence *quasiperiodic*).

Especially if the system's nonintegrable term is relatively weak, its phase space is bound to be full of these so-called [KAM surfaces](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser_theory).